# Why does this connection checker not work?

Tags: c, networking

I'm trying to implement a simple function to check if a server is listening on a specific port. I have a requirement that the call must be portable and non-blocking so I cannot just rely on connect().

`FD_ISSET(sock, &write_set)` seem to return true even if the remote service is down.

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

int check_connection(const char* ip_address, int port) {
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    int sock, flags;

    // Create a socket
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set server address parameters
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    // Convert IP address to binary form and set it in the server address structure
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ip_address, &server_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("Invalid IP address");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    // Set socket to non-blocking mode
    if ((flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0)) < 0 || fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to set socket to non-blocking mode");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    // Connect to the server
    int result = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    printf("connect() -> res: %d\n", result);

    if (result < 0 && errno != EINPROGRESS) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    // Check if the connection is established
    fd_set write_set;
    FD_ZERO(&write_set);
    FD_SET(sock, &write_set);
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    result = select(sock + 1, NULL, &write_set, NULL, &timeout);
    
    printf("select() -> res: %d\n", result);

    if (result <= 0 || !FD_ISSET(sock, &write_set)) {
        perror("Connection timed out or failed");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    // Connection successful
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc == 3) {
        if(check_connection(argv[1], atoi(argv[2])) == 0) {
            printf("Service is up\n");
        } else {
            printf("Service is down\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("usage:\n");
        
        printf("  %s <ip> <port>\n", argv[0]);
    }
}
```

**Results**

This the output I get. Verifying with netcat.

Test for service that is up

```
$ ./main 10.0.1.100 80
connect() -> res: -1
select() -> res: 1
Service is up

$ nc -vz 10.0.1.100 80
Connection to 10.0.1.100 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

Test for service that is down

```
$ ./main 10.0.1.100 443
connect() -> res: -1
select() -> res: 1
Service is up

$ nc -vz 10.0.1.100 443
nc: connect to 10.0.1.100 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: `connect() -> res: -1` ?

Comment: Since it is non-blocking, connect return -1 with errno = EINPROGRESS

Comment: is that how it tells you the connect finished?

Comment: Okay, but in that mode does it actually do anything with the connection until you try to send something?

Comment: That seem to be the case, adding a send() I was able to determine if the connection was up or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `select` rerurn successffully, you should `getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ...)` to get the *actual* state of the connection.
The man page is very clear:

> The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be
> completed immediately, it is possible to select(2) or poll(2)
> for completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After
> select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read
> the SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine
> whether connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is
> zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual
> error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the
> failure).